# SQL multiple rows into single row, but not always

Tags: sql-server, pivot, union

I have a real-time database that shows call center agents when they are logged in. An agent can login as voice agent or a chat agent or both, each login is displayed on a separate row;

If she logs on to both;

```
 AgentID | State    |ReasonCode  |LoginDur  |StateDur       |Domain
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
   1301    | NotReady   |Lunch       |01:23:12  |00:23:21       |1
   1301    | Ready      |Undefined   |00:57:12  |00:00:12       |5
```

Domain 1 for voice login and 5 for chat login and AgentID being common denominator. Now what  I would like to do is to combine both in a single row;

```
 AgtID | V-State |V-ReCode |V-LogDur |V-StDur |C-State|C-RCode  |C-LogDur  |C-StDur |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1301    |NotReady|Lunch    |01:23:12 |00:23:21|Ready  |Undefined|00:57:12  |00:00:12
```

If agent is logged on as both voice and chat agent, I can achieve that using the query below;

```
    SELECT AgentID, V-State, V-StDur, V-LogDur, V-RCode, C-State, C-StDur, C-LogDur, C-RCode 
FROM(SELECT
ART1.AgentID AS AgentID,
ART1.AgtState AS V-State,
ART2.AgtState AS C-State,
ART1.StateDur AS V-StDur,
ART2.StateDur AS C-StDur,
ART1.LoginDur AS V-LogDur,
ART2.LoginDur AS C-LogDur,
ART1.ReasonCode AS V-RCode,
ART2.ReasonCode AS C-RCode
FROM AgentRealTime ART1, AgentRealTime ART2
WHERE ART1.AgentID = ART2.AgentID AND
ART1.DomainID = 1 AND ART2.DomainID=5
)
AS AGRT
```

However this only works if agent is logged on to both. I have two other cases to cover; if agent logs on as voice agent only or chat agent only. For Voice-only logins, I use this query;

```
    SELECT
AgentID=ART.AgentID,
V-State=ART.AgtState,
C-State=NULL,
V-StDur=ART.StateDur,
C-StDur=NULL,
V-LogDur=ART.LoginDur,
C-LogDur=NULL,
V-RCode=ART.ReasonCode,
C-RCode=NULL
FROM AgentRealTime ART
WHERE ART.DomainID = 1
```

For chat-only logins I use this

```
    SELECT
AgentID=ART.AgentID,
V-State=NULL,
C-State=ART.AgtState,
V-StDur=NULL,
C-StDur=ART.StateDur,
V-LogDur=NULL,
C-LogDur=ART.LoginDur,
V-RCode=NULL,
C-RCode=ART.ReasonCode
FROM AgentRealTime ART
WHERE ART.DomainID = 5
```

and I UNION all three queries. If agent is logged on voice-only or chat-only, this overall query shows a single row.But I end up with three rows like this if agent is logged on to both;

```
AgtID | V-State |V-ReCode |V-LogDur |V-StDur |C-State|C-RCode  |C-LogDur  |C-StDur |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1301    |NotReady|Lunch    |01:23:12 |00:23:21|NULL   |NULL |NULL  |NULL

AgtID | V-State |V-ReCode |V-LogDur |V-StDur |C-State|C-RCode  |C-LogDur  |C-StDur |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1301    |NotReady|Lunch    |01:23:12 |00:23:21|Ready  |Undefined|00:57:12  |00:00:12

AgtID | V-State |V-ReCode |V-LogDur |V-StDur |C-State|C-RCode  |C-LogDur  |C-StDur |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1301    |NULL|NULL     |NULL |NULL  |Ready  |Undefined|00:57:12  |00:00:12
```

How can I sum those three rows as a single row if agent is logged into both voice and chat? Or any other approach you can recommend for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, I'll explain mostly in pseudo code since you seem to know what you are doing.

Option 1: In your latter two queries you can add AND NOT EXISTS/NOT IN

I rewrote your where clause slightly to be use INNER JOIN

> > Query 2
> >
> > SELECT....
> >
> > WHERE ART.DomainID = 5
> >
> > AND ART.AgentID NOT IN
> >
> > (SELECT ART1.AgentID
> >
> > FROM        AgentRealTime ART1
> >
> > INNER JOIN  AgentRealTime ART2 ON ART1.AgentID = ART2.AgentID
> >
> > WHERE ART1.DomainID = 1
> >
> > AND   ART2.DomainID=5)

Have the same condition in for Query 3

Option 2: Insert values into a temp table for first query. Then in each additional query check the AgentID does not exist in your table. You can do this several ways, I prefer a left join

Query 1 -> into temptable

> > Query 2 ->
> >     SELECT ....
> >
> > FROM AgentRealTime ART
> >
> > LEFT JOIN temptable t ON ART.agentID = t.agentID
> >
> > WHERE ART.DomainID = 1
> >
> > AND t.agentID IS NULL

Personally I prefer the #temp table route since you can easily enhance your report and a bunch of sub-queries and unions get confusing after a while. Also you can play around with the code to make it efficient.

Hope this helps, my first attempt at trying to answer a post.

Answer (score 0):

You just need full outer join:

```
SELECT AgentID, V-State, V-StDur, V-LogDur, V-RCode, C-State, C-StDur, C-LogDur, C-RCode 
FROM(SELECT
COALEASE(ART1.AgentID,ART2.AgentID) AS AgentID,
ART1.AgtState AS V-State,
ART2.AgtState AS C-State,
ART1.StateDur AS V-StDur,
ART2.StateDur AS C-StDur,
ART1.LoginDur AS V-LogDur,
ART2.LoginDur AS C-LogDur,
ART1.ReasonCode AS V-RCode,
ART2.ReasonCode AS C-RCode
FROM AgentRealTime ART1 
FULL OUTER JOIN AgentRealTime ART2
ON ART1.AgentID = ART2.AgentID AND
WHERE ART1.DomainID = 1 AND ART2.DomainID=5 
)
AS AGRT
```

AgentId need use coalease.